# .JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: expo

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";

import NotVerifiedToVerify from "../pages/volunteer/Verification/NotVerifiedList";

import VerifiedToNotVerify from "../pages/volunteer/Verification/VerifiedToNotVerify";

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()

export default function VerifyTopTabNavigation({route}){

```
const { groupid,groupname } = route.params;


return(
    <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen 
        name="NotVerified" 
        component={NotVerifiedToVerify} 
        initialParams={ {groupid,groupname} }
       
         />
        <Tab.Screen 
        name="Verified" 
        component={VerifiedToNotVerify}  
        initialParams={ {groupid,groupname} }
       
        />
    </Tab.Navigator>
)
```

}

The Android app crashes when navigating to the top tab.Does anyone know how to solve the issue?